# Can volatile be problematic even when there is a single writer thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

If there is a single writer thread and a single reader thread can we still  have a race condition with a volatile variable.
Like in the code below is it possible that in one case the writer thread checks value of x as zero does nothing context switch occurs and reader thread also see's x value as 0.
While in one case the writer thread checks value of x as zero increments it by 1 flushes it to main memory( as x is volatile) ,context switch occurs and reader thread see's x value as 1.
I was just wondering whether volatile would be sufficient in this use case or we need to go with synchronized to avoid race condition

I have tried executing the below code but its giving me same result always

```
public class VolatileSingleWriterClarity {
    static volatile int x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(VolatileSingleWriterClarity::writer).start();
        new Thread(VolatileSingleWriterClarity::reader).start();
    }

    public static void reader() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void writer() {
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Normal compiled code, in high level languages, don't do "flush" to "main memory". It doesn't messes with CPU caches, ever.

Answer (score 1):

> Like in the code below is it possible that in one case the writer thread checks value of x as zero does nothing context switch occurs and reader thread also see's x value as 0.

Yes, that's absolutely possible. Even though `x` is volatile, `x++` involves two completely separate operations: a volatile read, then a volatile write. Each of those operations is atomic, but it's absolutely possible for a context switch to happen in between them. (It's also possible for the two threads to run on completely separate processor cores, so even *without* a context switch it's possible for the reader to read the original value while the writer is just about to write the new value.)

---

> I was just wondering whether volatile would be sufficient in this use case or we need to go with synchronized to avoid race condition

`synchronized` won't really help here. You seem to be worried about preventing this scenario (which `volatile` allows but `synchronized` can prevent):

- writer thread reads original value of `x`
- reader thread reads original value of `x`, prints it
- writer thread writes new value of `x`, which never gets read

but it's exactly equivalent to this scenario (which both `volatile` and `synchronized` allow):

- reader thread reads original value of `x`, prints it
- writer thread reads original value of `x`
- writer thread writes new value of `x`, which never gets read

so there's no point "fixing" the one without fixing the other.

If you want to ensure that the reader thread doesn't read `x` until after the writer thread has written to it, you'll need to do something more sophisticated, e.g. using `wait` and `notify`.

Comment: Or avoid manual synchronization whenever possible and just use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: @chrylis: I think you must be misunderstanding something. Replacing `synchronized` with `AtomicInteger` in this question and answer would change nothing. (And I don't think your advice is good advice, anyway.)

Comment: What? Replacing `int x` with `AtomicInteger x` is *the library solution intended for this exact problem*.

Comment: @chrylis: No, it's *the library solution intended for a completely different problem*. Any situation where `AtomicInteger` works, `synchronized` also works; the advantage of `AtomicInteger` is simply that it achieves those guarantees without locking/blocking on most architectures. (Which is great, and I use it regularly. But when `synchronized` doesn't prevent a certain undesired ordering of actions, you can be certain that `AtomicInteger` won't prevent it, either.)

Comment: @chrylis: Addendum: I've just realized that my previous responses were understatement; `AtomicInteger` is exactly the same as `volatile` for the OP's example, not even as strong a guarantee as `synchronized`. So I really can't imagine why you brought it up. (But it doesn't really matter, because as I explained in this answer, even the extra `synchronized` guarantee wouldn't change anything very meaningful here. So none of them is any better or any worse than the other two.)